# Heathrow transit - timing and visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, lhr

I am flying Delhi-Lisbon and have a transit in Heathrow. My jet flight from Delhi arrives at terminal 4 at 5:40 PM and I have a TAP Portugal flight from Terminal 2 at 7:55 PM. This is single e ticket with both flight segments listed on the same ticket, so I am assuming my baggage will be checked through to Lisbon.

Do I need a Visa transiting at Heathrow and also is this enough time to make the connection? I am an Indian citizen with a valid US visa, so technically I am expecting as per UK website. But I am not sure given the fact that I need to take a train/bus to change terminals.

Answer (score 1):

When transiting airside at Heathrow, dedicated buses will transport you between the terminals, meaning you will not have to clear immigration.

[For this type of transit](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no), you do **not** need a visa, owing to your valid US visa.

[If you did need to clear immigration](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes) (to pick up baggage for example, which you won't because you have a single ticket), you would need a visa to do so, because then, a US visa holder also needs to be on a journey to/from the US.

However, since there are airside buses, which means you don't need to clear immigration, your US visa alone means **you can do this trip without a UK visa**.

As for the timing, you will be OK according to [Heathrow's flight connection planner](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections/personal-connection-planner/9W122/TP369/19-NOV-2016/19-NOV-2016/2/6A): however even if you miss the connection (such as if your inbound from Delhi is delayed), the airline will take care of you since the trip is on a single ticket.